# Missing } in Lua

Tags: lua

I got a issue with this Lua script where it says that its missing on line 46 a ´}´, what am I missing here? I marked it in the code, anyone got a clue, probably something simple?

```
local function Peacekeeper_OnCheckArea(creature)
    for k, player in pairs(GetPlayersInMap(creature:GetMapId())) do
        if(player) then
            if (player:GetAreaId() == creature:GetAreaId()) then
                local point = player:GetX(), player:GetY()  --<-- Line 46**
                if(isInArea(point)) then
                    player:SetPvP(false)
                else
                    player:SetPvP(true)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm curious about what implementation of Lua you are using. The two versions of the standard implementation that I tested (5.2, 5.1.2) do not give any error. And, I'd say that's consistent with the syntax definition and [description](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.3) given in the current (5.2) manual.

Comment: @TomBlodget I'd guess he's using a Lua-aware IDE of some sort, but hard to tell. I'd have thought that the lua error would have been inside the isInArea().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `local point` should be assigned a table. Like this:

```
local point = { player.GetX(), player.GetY() }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Totally forgot about that. Will put you as answered, gotto wait 5 minutes though.